# Javascript fires two events - onkeypress and onclick

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, dom-events, onkeypress

Problem is when I press a key over a radio button, element `MyFunc` fires twice - once for `onkeypress` event, another time for "click" event.

Question "Why?" I need to handle this by two different ways, but now I can not recognize what initial event was. When I click a mouse it fires just for "click" event.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" onkeypress="MyFunc(event, this)" onclick="MyFunc(event, this)" name="myList" id="MyId_1" />Topic 1
        <input type="radio" onkeypress="MyFunc(event, this)" onclick="MyFunc(event, this)" name="myList" id="MyId_2" />Topic 2
    </li>
</ul>

function MyFunc(e, obj) {
    alert(e.type); // alerts "keypress" and then "click"
    // Do my stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If 2 events are being fired during pressing a key then check `event.detail` property in `onClick` function.
if `event.detail = 0` then it means that mouse was not clicked on that element and we can ignore it.
[event.detail](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrxdxdw.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` Event is fired, when the radio button gets selected. Since you select it by pressing a key, both events will get fired. First the `onkeypress` event and then the `onclick` event.

Comment: But how do you prevent this from occuring?

Comment: You can't prevent this behaviour as far as I know.

Comment: It is very strange. What is the point to handle these events together? :-/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done and without resorting to frameworks which are always bulky and slow. The trick is to record which event happened at what point in time and then on top of that to work within a time frame. When you trigger the `keypress` event the `click` event is triggered immediately afterwards, here is a list of how quickly the `click` event is triggered after the `keypress` event...

**Chrome 39.0**: 0ms

**Firefox 31.0 ESR**: 18~20ms

**IE 11**: 2~4ms

**Opera 12.1**: 0ms

Chrome and (real) Opera don't wait, IE is reasonably quick and Firefox takes it's time so-to-speak; the range to work with (at least on my system) is 0~20 ms. Programmatically I'll set the limit to 50ms for people still using junky computers that are too busy with the 150 useless processes in the background.

Note you'll have to utilize the `window` global level events though this seems to work reliably for me in all the browsers that I mentioned.

```
var option = new function() {this.name = '';}


window.onclick = function(event)
{
 option.clickDate = new Date().getTime();
}


window.onkeypress = function(event)
{
 option.keyCode = event.keyCode;
 option.keyCodeDate = new Date().getTime();
}


function MyFunc(e,obj)
{
 if (option.keyCodeDate && option.clickDate && 
 (
  (option.clickDate - option.keyCodeDate)>=0 && 
  (option.clickDate - option.keyCodeDate)<51)
 {alert('keypress event');}
 else {alert('click event');}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a 3rd parameter to your function

```
function MyFunc(e, obj, click) {
    if (click) { } // do stuff
    else { } // do other stuff
}
```

Now add in a bool to your events...

```
<input type="radio" onkeypress="MyFunc(event, this, false)" onclick="MyFunc(event, this, true)" name="myList" id="MyId_1" />Topic 1
<input type="radio" onkeypress="MyFunc(event, this, false)" onclick="MyFunc(event, this, true)" name="myList" id="MyId_2" />Topic 2
```

Comment: The problem is that they fire simultaneously. I can recognize what was clicked using e.type property. It returns "keypress" or "click".

Answer (score 0):

I would create two separate handlers: one for the click event and one for they keypress.

Then your handlers can extract whatever you need from the event and call a third function that has the common logic.

Your onkeypress would have to ignore the event for the space and enter keys. I don't understand why you are listening to the keypress event though. Could you elaborate? If you explain what you'll do, maybe we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A key event is for keyboard only users to activate a button, but if you're using a button "click" should be the only event needed as it gets fired when pressing SPACE BAR.  If you have events on a custom control, "key" event and "click" can both be used and will not fire together.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the properties `.type` and `.detail` as suggested. `type` stays as `click` on both firefox and chromium. `detail` stays as `0` on chromium, but changes to `1` when actually clicking with the mouse on firefox. But `.x` and `.y` do change on both firefox and chromium when clicking with mouse, while remaining as `0` when the event originates from keyboard actions.

Answer (score -1):

Use onMouseDown instead of onclick within JavaScript and for consistency add you onKeyPress event here too - taking the event out of the HTML tag.

Sudo Code:

```
var myRadioButton = document.getElementById('radio');

myRadioButton.addListener("radioClick",onMouseDown);
myRadioButton.addListener("radioKey",onKeyPress);

radioClick()
{
 //code to do stuff
}
```

Check out jQuery: http://jquery.com/ for the actual code and easy way to write your JavaScript.

Comment: I will try it. I think I tryed onMouseDown, but I worked like OnClick. Maybe addListener helps. Will come back soon with results.

Comment: I've tried this solution using jQuery. It did not help. "OnMouseDown" did not fired anything. It just did not call my function. If I user "OnClick" with addListener it gives the same problem. I do not have any solution right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Great that you mentioned consistency but then you bombed it by suggesting a framework. If I had searched for this issue via Google this page wouldn't have come up because I -jquery to find answers, not dumping bandwidth on users. Please stick to real JavaScript.