# Filter 'onchange' 'onkeypress'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way how to handle only one of these events if both of them fired? If I  change value and press key I end up rebinding grid twice because events arrive in sequentially.  I understand that what I am getting is correct behaviour and I am getting what I asked for, but I need a way how to stop the second event from propagation. I am looking for solution at the event level (not `isGridBinded` flag).

```
$(op.$txtBox).on('change keypress', function (e) {
        if ((e.keyCode == 13 && e.type == 'keypress')  || e.type == 'change') {
            localWidget._rebindGrid();
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363360/javascript-fires-two-events-onkeypress-and-onclick similar issue - no answer.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle with relevant code?!

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ  your link is relative to delegation, here OP doesn't delegate events

Comment: you have a mistake in your fiddle the if statement should also check for keyup if you handling keyup. if you change the keyup back to keypress, run it and then type in value, loose focus from the field then type in other value and press enter you will get two logs.

Comment: @roasted check again this link is for .on as OP is asking.

Comment: @Bobby_D_ correct, sorry for the mistake!

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ  Here OP is using .on() syntax relative/equivalent to bind, not to delegate/live. Again, this is not OP's issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keyup event instead.

Otherwise, the only way i can think is to throttle it using a timeout:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/td5Xm/)

```
(function () {
    var timeout;
    $('input').on('change keypress', function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            if ((e.keyCode == 13 && e.type == 'keypress') || e.type == 'change') {
                console.log(1);
            }
        }, 0);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the keyup did the trick, the timeout solution would get me around the issue as well. Interesting that these two events behaves differently, I will read up on it a little

Comment: Further more here is the best solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector   -   http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

Answer (score 0):

Use the events like that:

```
$(op.$txtBox).on({
    change: function(){
          localWidget._rebindGrid();
     },
     keypress: function(e){
         if(e.keyCode == 13)
            localWidget._rebindGrid();
     },
});
```

Reference:
[JQuery .on() method with multiple event handlers to one selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector)

OR you can use the [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function of jQUery.

Comment: what this would change to OP's issue?

Comment: @roasted I am updating the code.

Comment: @roasted its working try with change the console.log with alert.

Comment: Sorry but for debugging you need to use console not alert. Alert change some browser's behaviour specially for events. BTW, here, this still alert twice if you type something in the input (onchange get fired if input value change, not if still the same)  http://jsfiddle.net/rEwML/